# calling function in jQuery , i am passing some value dynamically with comma and single quotes but its not coming properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am calling a jquery function with some parameter which having comma and single quotes.but its not coming according to my needs.
Below is my calling function

```
onclick=\"setRowId(' + @rowCount + ',\"' + @item.EduQualification + '"\ ,\"' + @item.Year +'"\,\"' + @item.ScolColjBoard + '\' )\"
```

and my called function is mentioned below:-

```
function setRowId(rowCount, rowData1, rowData2, rowData3)
```

but while i am checking in browser debbuger mode its showing like this:-

```
onclick=\"setRowId(' + 1+ ',\"' + abc+ '"\ ,\"' + 2017+'"\,\"' + cbse+ '\' )\"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values are coming from your server side ASP code you don't need to append them. You can just put the values directly in the HTML using Razor syntax:

```html
onclick="setRowId('@rowCount','@item.EduQualification','@item.Year','@item.ScolColjBoard')"
```

You should note that it would be much better practice to instead use an unobtrusive event handler and place the required values in `data` attributes on the element, something like this:

```js
$('.set-row').click(function() {
  var $a = $(this);
  var rowcount = $a.data('row-count');
  var eduQualification = $a.data('edu-qualification');
  var year = $a.data('year');
  var scolColjBoard = $a.data('scol-col-jboard');
  
  console.log(rowcount, eduQualification, year, scolColjBoard);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="set-row" data-row-count="1" data-edu-qualification="abc" data-year="2017" data-scol-col-jboard="cbse">Click me</a>
```